# How can I set different adapter for ViewPager ?

Tags: android

I read this tutorial

http://blog.stylingandroid.com/archives/542

There are 3 pages in ViewPager and they have the same data in ListView.

How can I make each page has different adapter ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are following the code from that blog post, in `instantiateItem()`, create a different adapter for each page, based upon the supplied `position`.

Comment: Could you give me some example ?
Actually I'm pretty confuse about these codes.

Comment: @aratn0n: "Could you give me some example ?" -- not based off of that blog post. Here is a directory of six sample `ViewPager` apps: https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/ViewPager